# Array2 with only it's full fields overwrites fields in Array1?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't find a way at all to do this. I need to overwrite Array1 with only the fields that have a value (fields which aren't empty `''`) from Array2 and make Array3 out of them. What is a good way to do this?

```js
Array1 = ['cookie', 'pancake', '', '', 'brownie']
Array2 = ['', '', 'muffin', '', 'cake']

// gives
Array3 = ['cookie', 'pancake', 'muffin', '', 'cake']
```

Comment: That's the wrong question to ask; SO is not a general help forum, it's for helping you solve problems with you're using/have written. So if you're posting to Stackoverflow, your question is "I tried the following, and it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why,  what am I doing wrong?". If you haven't written _any_ code yourself yet, [start writing some code yourself, first](/help/how-to-ask), because it's too soon to ask on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map()` on `Array1`. Check if the element of `Array1` is empty change return element of `Array2` on that index otherwise return the element itself.

```js
let Array1 = ['cookie', 'pancake', '', '', 'brownie']
let Array2 = ['', '', 'muffin', '', 'cake']
let Array3 = Array1.map((x, i) => x === '' ? Array2[i] : x);
console.log(Array3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over `Array1` if it's value is non empty return it else return value on respective index from `Array2`

```js
let Array1 = ['cookie', 'pancake', '', '', 'brownie']
let Array2 = ['', '', 'muffin', '', 'cake']


let op = Array1.map((val,i)=> val !== '' ?  val : Array2[i] )

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Array1 = ['cookie', 'pancake', '', '', 'brownie']
Array2 = ['', '', 'muffin', '', 'cake']

const combineArrays =(a1,a2)=>a1.map(
  (val,i)=>a2[i]?a2[i]:val)

combineArrays(Array1, Array2);
```

UPDATE: this might be a really inscrutable piece of code if you're an inexperienced programmer, so here's an equivalent version without the lambdas and trinary and with some comments:

```
const combineArrays = function(a1,a2){     //a1 is the original array
  return a1.map(        //do the function below to everything in array a1
    function(val, i){        // i is the index, which lets you refer to the same element in a2
      if(a2[i])        // this will be false if a2[i] is '' 
      {return a2[i]}      //take the value from the second array
      else {return val}      //otherwise keep the value from the first array
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be good solution here. Using map() check the empty value of each element, if empty the get the same index value from `Array2`.

```js
const Array1 = ['cookie', 'pancake', '', '', 'brownie']
const Array2 = ['', '', 'muffin', '', 'cake']
    
const result = Array1.map((i, k) => (!i && (i = Array2[k]), i))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `i = i`?

Comment: Overriding `i` from Array2 if necessary but could be simplified by ternary what did other.